# Create a ninject Dependency with static constructor

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ninject

I have created a Unit of work wrapper for my Nhibernate data access methods. I initialise my Session Factory inside the Static Constructor of the UnitOfWork class, hoping to have it initialised once and only once.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
  private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
  static UnitOfWork()
    {
        var oracleConfiguration = OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONNECTION_STRING].ConnectionString);
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                          .Database(oracleConfiguration)
                          .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add<MyMap>())
                          .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

I then bind this unitOfWork dependency with Ninject Kernel during my application startup and then expect Ninject to resolve it in my data access repository's constructor. (I am using Constructor injection).

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
         Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }                                                                       
}
```

But after resolution, I could understand that the code inside the static constructor was never executed during object creation and as a result my Nhibernate Session factory is null.

I am definitely sure that I am missing something here. Could some one help me understand what is the correct way to use static constructor in Ninject ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to set your unit of work static. It should work without static keyword

Comment: If I don't set it to static, with my current Ninject Binding Configuration, it would result in Ninject IOC creating separate Session Factories for each resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You want your Uow constructor to be executed only once, thus you are declaring it static. Why not, but it should not compile with an access modifier (the `public` keyword). Static constructor does not accept access modifiers (or arguments). Are you sure your code is valid?

I guess you have actually tried without the invalid access modifier.

I do not know how a type could be used without triggering its static constructor first. Maybe NInject is able of doing that. In such case, just fallback to a cleaner solution: add your session factory to NInject with a singleton life-cycle and appropriate code to instantiate it (basically what your current Uow constructor does), and setup your Uow for having it as a dependency.

Comment: My bad, I typed the code myself in the question and forgot about the access modifier in my Static Constructor. I shall correct it now. I tried your suggestion and it worked as expected as well. My binding is "Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InSingletonScope();" and I have changed my static constructor to Public Instance Constructor. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dinny it's culture to vote/rate answers to your question, you should especially accept the best answer actually answering your question and it's also common to vote on the other answers. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer